# Mac Mini Server Push Notification to MacBook

Tags: osx-server, macos

is it possible to get the push notifications from my Mac mini Server 10.9 on my MacBook with 10.9? At least the Server.app relevant stuff?

Comment: how familiar are you with bash/ruby scripting?

Comment: non-programer here. I thought this is would be a feature of OS X Server…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be indeed push notifications are built-in into Mavericks Server.

[Here](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/enable-push-notifications-in-mavericks-server/) is a tutorial describing the process how to activate push notifications in Mavericks Server.

Comment: ok, I already did this. But can I get push notifications for the Server.app on my Macbook?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed. It’s in the Server.app Alerts->Delivery